# Can OpenOffice avoid most Microsoft VBA virus?

Tags: openoffice, vba

Our office often get infected with VBA virus (don't know why). We have encountered VBA virus that inject macro to excel sheets, there have been macro that run whenever a new excel sheet is open etc.

SO we're consider to use OpenOffice to replace Microsoft Office thinking that OpenOffice should be able to evade most VBA Macro virus - is that true?

Comment: What VBA virus are you referring to? Plus this question would be better asked on Stack Overflow where the VBA experts are

Comment: as this is more an application usage, i think it more appropriate here than SO, but more people think that so, i'll move it.

Comment: As you are having VBA issues then they may be solvable - better to look at cure first rather than moving apps for prevention. cheers

Comment: what is the cure? I tried AVG anti-virus, but it doesn't pick up the virus location.

Comment: what is the problem? You need to specify what is happening.

Comment: Also, macros (including VBA) could be disabled in the MS Office settings, unless you need them enabled for another reason. Do your documents come from an external source? Actually, if memory serves, MS Office does not execute macros automatically, instead giving a nice big warning. Maybe remind your colleagues/employees to click no? ;)

Comment: Office 2007 onwards also support macro-free documents which get any macros stripped out when saving.  Tell your people that when they save a document they need to "save as" then change the format to the macro-free format.  xlsx  is the Excel macro-free extension, and docx is the Word macro-free extension.

Comment: Why not give it a try with a few infected documents and an OpenOffice installation?

Comment: it would be best to determine the source of the macros. They maybe in someone's personal.xls (depending upon version) and so that is the actual source that is injecting it. But you can set security in all versions to not allow macros unless you authorize them

Answer (score 0):

Open office doesn't run VBA scripts so VBA viruses wont work, but OpenOffice has OpenOffice.org BASIC, that is OpenOffices own version of VBA, that will have a lot less viruses but will still have Viruses. OpenOffice will be a lot safer if you need to use macro's to speed things up but if you don't use macros then Office can be just as safe. An alternative to openoffice is LibreOffice that is a openoffice derivative that is a lot more popular, more fetures and is also free. LibreOffice still has Basic though.
I have only used open office a couple times so I can't give you a way to stop openoffice viruses on openoffice but I can tell you how to stop VBA for Microsoft Word and how to stop Basic scripts on LibreOffice, its down below:

In word (I'm using word 2010) go into the options then open the 'Trust Center' tab and then click on the 'Trust Center Settings...' button then in there open the 'Macro Settings' tab then check 'Disable all macros without notification' (unless you use VBA then click 'Disable all macros with notification')(this will stop people from getting tricked by documents and turning them on) then click ok at the bottom of both windows and then it should be a bit safer. This should work for Microsoft excel and PowerPoint as well.
Also check this article out: [Click here to see a Microsoft artical](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-or-disable-macros-in-Office-documents-7B4FDD2E-174F-47E2-9611-9EFE4F860B12)

LibreOffice (I'm using version 6.0.7.3) go to tools>Options. this will bring up a dialog box, click the dropdown for libreoffice and click security. You will see Macro Security button on the left. Click it. Another dialog box will appear, click the option you feel is the best and then go into the Trusted source to configure trusted locaitons and certificates.

If this keeps happening then just get the IT man to block all macro documents, they have a m at the end of the extension so a word document with out vba would be '.doc' or '.docx' when one that does have VBA would be '.docm'. So just block them.

Hopes this helps.

Comment: "Open office does run VBA scripts" This answer is incorrect - it doesn't. It uses OpenOffice.org BASIC. [Macros written for MS Word for instance cannot be executed via OpenOffice.org; you'll need to re-write them.](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/Macros/Can_I_use_my_Microsoft_Office_macros%3F)